# Listing all comments for a video in YouTube API 3.0

Tags: youtube-api

Is it possible to get all comments for a video with the new (experimental) YouTube API v 3.0?

I only found how to get "activities" (in their terminology comment is a kind of activity) originating from a given account.

The api page says the api is not feature complete, so it is quite possible that functionality is not yet made available. Although I might've just missed it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure 3.0 can only get a comment count right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no support for retrieving comments using v3 of the API. We can't make any commitments to add in support for reading/writing comments at this time, so if your application depends on them, using v2 is required.

Comment: Since v2 has now been officially depreciated - is there *any* supported way to read or write comments via the API?

Comment: @jackweirdy Yes, you should keep using the v2 API. Depreciated does not mean Unsupported. Youtube promises they will add the functionality to v3 API "well before" the v2 is shut down in April 2015. Source: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2014/03/committing-to-youtube-data-api-v3.html

Comment: @Jeff Since it is already Feb 2015, any news if the 3.0 Version will have support for YouTube comments. I could not find any API for retrieving comments in 3.0